# Resume suddenly fails after suspend on Ubuntu 11.10 (was working before)

Tags: ubuntu, suspend

My suspend has always worked but stopped doing so yesterday. The days before I fiddled around a bit with Xorg, but I have reverted all those changes already. What I was working on was vaapi support and installed xbmc. I also updated Xorg from the Ubuntu repository yesterday. I tried to manually downgrade the updated packages which I got from `/var/log/apt` but resuming from suspend would still not work.

I have a Lenovo E320 with a Sandy Bridge chipset. After A suspend the screen stays back, CTRL+ALT+F1 / F7 don't do anything. I even put a script into `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` which writes into /var/log/wakeup but it does not print anything. Putting the lid down again doesn't put the laptop into suspend again.

I put the computer to sleep 15:55, woke it up 15:56 and force shut it down 15:57 by long pressing the power button. Then 15:58 I restarted it. This is the resulting syslog:
http://pastebin.com/ih9CKb0t

I will provide any other logs required!

Thank you very much for your help,
Fred

Comment: This thread has some good suggestions albeit 11.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61495/lenovo-ideapad-s10-3-doesnt-resume-from-suspend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was a hardware fault. Lenovo changed my mainboard and RAM and now it works (with the same hard disk image).